# Can't install helm on Debian (Pop_OS) because of a 404. How can I get around that?

Tags: debian, google-cloud

I am running this script from the cloud.google.com doc:

```
# Create environment variable for correct distribution
export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)"

# Add the Cloud SDK distribution URI as a package source
echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

# Import the Google Cloud Platform public key
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

# Update the package list and install the Cloud SDK
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

Which results in:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   653  100   653    0     0   3710      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3710
OK
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                 
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                                                   
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                                                                                   
Ign:6 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-eoan InRelease                                                                            
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease                                                             
Hit:8 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary eoan InRelease                                                                        
Hit:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease   
Hit:5 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease
Err:11 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 172.217.19.206 80]
Hit:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any idea how I can still get this somehow?

Comment: Are you using Debian, Pop!_OS, or Ubuntu? Mixing all three's repositories is not going to work out as you can see.

Comment: I am using Pop!_OS. I was not aware that this is somehow relevant when it says `http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-eoan` is not reachable @kemotep

Comment: Have you followed the steps as exactly [outlined here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get)? The error is not that the repository is unreachable it is that the repository does not have a release file and cannot verify anything it would download from there. [Here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48736403/is-there-a-repository-engine-issue-for-google-cloud-datalab-on-linux-mint-18-3) outlining people having issues using an Ubuntu based distro (read: NOT Ubuntu or Debian which is what is supported). They solve the issue via manual installation.